# How to copy a ksh associative array?

Tags: arrays, associative-array, ksh, copying

Is there a way to copy an associative array? I realize that regular arrays can be copied easily with a one liner as such:

```
set -A NEW_ARRAY $(echo ${OTHER_ARRAY[*]})
```

but doing so with associative arrays just gives you the values in that manner.

I know about `nameref` but I'm interested in knowing if there's a way of copying the array such that the original array isn't affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

untested:

```
typeset -A NEW_ARRAY
for key in "${!OTHER_ARRAY[@]}"; do
    NEW_ARRAY["$key"]="${OTHER_ARRAY[$key]}"
done
```

tested:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh93

OTHER_ARRAY=( [Key1]="Val1" [Key2]="Val2" [Key3]="Val3" )

echo Keys: ${!OTHER_ARRAY[*]}
echo Values: ${OTHER_ARRAY[*]}

typeset -A NEW_ARRAY
for key in "${!OTHER_ARRAY[@]}"; do
    NEW_ARRAY["$key"]="${OTHER_ARRAY[$key]}"
done

echo Keys: ${!NEW_ARRAY[*]}
echo Values: ${NEW_ARRAY[*]}
```

Result:

```
/home/exuser>./a
Keys: Key3 Key1 Key2
Values: Val3 Val1 Val2
Keys: Key3 Key1 Key2
Values: Val3 Val1 Val2
```

Comment: Why not just  `NEW_ARRAY["$key"]="${OTHER_ARRAY[$key]}"` for the assignment, the typeset and for look look good however. In any case I don't think the += will work as you expect.Don't have time to test this either.  @Nitrodist good luck!

Comment: Edited your answer to include the correct way of doing it. `+=` isn't valid syntax with associative array assignment. @shelter - your method works. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. Regarding `+=`, I don't have access to ksh93, but a [ksh93 manual](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh-man.html#Variable%20Assignments) indicates it should work: "In addition, a += can be used in place of the = to signify adding to or appending to the previous value. ... For compound assignments, the previous value is not unset and the new values are appended to the current ones provided that the types are compatible."