# How to copy Associative Array without for loop

Tags: bash, shell, sh, associative-array

I am looking for an efficient way to copy associative array because I am performing this action inside two nested for-loops in my main script.

Here's the general format which I am using in my main script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A oldLinks
oldLinks["A"]="linkA"
oldLinks["B"]="linkB"
oldLinks["C"]="linkC"
oldLinks["D"]="linkD"
```

```
#!/bin/bash
source exportThis.sh
declare -A copyLinks
for i in "${!oldLinks[@]}"; do 
 copyLinks[$i]=${oldLinks[$i]}
done
for k in "${!copyLinks[@]}"; do
  echo "$k -- ${copyLinks[$k]}"
done
```

When I do it this way in my main script, I am getting this error:

```
bash: copyLinks: "${oldLinks[@]}": must use subscript when assigning associative array
```

```
copyLinks=("${oldLinks[@]}")
```

Comment: The loop is the only way to do this. You don't have nested loops, though. The first loop does the copying, the second loop (which *follows* the first loop) isn't necessary; it just verifies that `copyLinks` contains the keyvalue pairs you want (and could be replaced by `declare -p copyLinks`).

Comment: What's wrong with the loop? Are you worried about speed?

Comment: In my main script I do have two nested loops where I am using data from array to do distcp commands.

Comment: [This ksh example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6651756/3776858) works with bash >= 4.0, too. `typeset` is obsolete. Replace it with `declare`.

Comment: Yes I am worried about the speed because the length of my associative array is 50.

Answer (score 2):

Just print old values and rename the variable value. Then source it. Ex. like this:

```
tmp=$(declare -p oldLinks)
eval "${tmp/oldLinks/copyLinks}"
```

`declare -p oldLinks` will print `declare -A oldLinks=([A]="linkA" [B]="linkB" [C]="linkC" [D]="linkD" )`. Then you substitute `oldLinks` for `copyLinks`, so it becomes `declare -A copyLinks=([A]="linkA" [B]="linkB" [C]="linkC" [D]="linkD" )`. Then execute it.

Comment: I'd be a little more comfortable about that if the `sed` expression were more narrowly written. Some versions of bash can put literal newlines in `declare -p` output (when such newlines are present in keys or values); in those, more than one substitution could take place even without the `g` flag on the sed expression.

Comment: ...of course, one could just replace sed with a parameter expansion; `${var/search/replace}` will only change `search` to `replace` once, no matter how many lines there are in the content of `var`. So this is generally a good approach, there's just room to tinker around the edges.

Comment: I'd second the use of eval; the solution below seems better to me.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, I just found out today how to use `paste` and some basic tricks to copy associative arrays.

```
declare -A oldLinks
oldLinks["A"]="linkA"
oldLinks["B"]="linkB"
oldLinks["C"]="linkC"
oldLinks["D"]="linkD"

declare -A copyLinks='('$(paste -d '=' <(printf '[%s]\n' "${!oldLinks[@]}") <(printf "'%s'\n" "${oldLinks[@]}"))')'
declare -p copyLinks
-> declare -A copyLinks=([D]="linkD" [C]="linkC" [B]="linkB" [A]="linkA" )
```

`paste` merges 2 or more files, by writing lines composed of the corresponding items of each file in sequence, separated by a tab or other.

Here we combine 2 pseudo-files created with `printf`, the first one being the list of keys of the original array, the second one being the list of its items. We use the delimiter option `-d '='` so that each line is writen in the form `[key]="item"`, and we finally add parentheses to each end before creating the new array with `declare -A array=(...)` (do no omit declare -A or it won't work).

It will maybe break in some complex situations but for integers and strings it works perfectly fine.

Comment: In my version of Bash (5.2.21) this produces only a String, no array

Answer (score 0):

Found another elegant solution:

```
tmpDef=$(typeset -p srcArray) && typeset -A targetArray="${tmpDef#*=}"
```

Taken from: [Make associative array from other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464626/making-associative-array-based-on-another-associative-array/464650#464650)